# How to remove View from Activity RootView

Tags: android, layout, view, viewgroup, rootview

I'm trying to remove an inflated view. This is how I inflate the view:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
mOverflowMenuView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.overflow_menu, vg);
```

And this is how I try to remove it from onBackPressed

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(mOverflowMenuView.getParent());
vg.removeView(mOverflowMenuView);
```

But I get a class cast exception:

```
03-11 22:47:31.848: E/AndroidRuntime(26357): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewRootImpl cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. It seems like my `View` were added to a `RelativeLayout` under the root. To get that `RelativeLayout` handle I had to do:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.board_root_view).getRootView();     
RelativeLayout v = (RelativeLayout)mOverflowListView.getParent();
vg.removeView(v);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting the classcastexception on the below line:

```
  ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
```

Then I would suggest that you place an id in the root view of your layout and then inflate it using the findViewById() directly and then use the removeView method.